# C++, Storing a String containing binary into a text file

Tags: c++, binaryfiles, fstream, ofstream, huffman-code

I am currently attempting to store a string containing binary code.

When I attempt to write this string to a text file it simply stores each 0 and 1 character in a string format, rather than storing it into 8 bit chunks as I require. This causes the file to be larger than intended, considering it uses 8 bits to store each 0 and 1.

Should I write the string to a .bin file instead of a .txt file?
If so how would I go about doing this, and if possible an example with some working code.

My thanks for any advice in advance.

```
   string encoded = "01010101";    
   ofstream myfile;   
   myfile.open ("encoded");   
   myfile <<  encoded;   
   myfile.close();
```

Clarification:
I have a string made up of 1's and 0's(resulting from a Huffman Tree), I wish to break this string up into 8 bit chunks, I wish to write each character represented by said chink to a compressed file.

Comment: Do you have a good reason for storing binary data in strings? Can't use something meant for storing binary data?

Comment: I am attempting to store binary resulting from encoding text through the use of a Huffman tree. The issue I am having is writing the binary to a file in a 8 bit compressed manner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Should I write the string to a .bin file instead of a .txt file?

If you wish so... But that wouldn't make a difference either. `ofstream` doesn't care about filenames. Just convert the string to a byte (`uint8_t`) and write that byte to the file:

```
string s = "10101010";
uint8_t byte = strtoul(s.c_str(), NULL, 2);
myfile << byte;
```

Comment: Like so? 

`string test = "01010101";
uint8_t byte = strtoul(test.c_str());
ofstream myfile3;
myfile3.open ("binary.txt");
myfile3 <<  test;
myfile3.close();` @H2CO3

Comment: @user2202417 Yes, except that I accidentally left out two arguments of `strtoul`. See edit.

Answer (score 1):

I'm only guessing since you don't show any code, but it seems you have a string containing the *characters* `'1'` and `'0'`. If you write that to a file of course it will be as a text. You need to convert it to integers first.

See e.g. [`std::stoi`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) or [`std::strtol`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtol) for functions to convert strings of arbitrary base to integers.

Answer (score 1):

[`std::bitset`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset) can convert a string to an integer.

```
std::bitset<8> bits("01010101");
cout << bits.to_ullong();
```